# CSS: margin/padding on IE cause floats to be placed incorrectly

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-float

I'm having trouble getting IE7 to float my elements correctly (FF and Chrome work as expected). I'd like to have the "Delete" buttons (here a span with class "sbutton") to be floated all the way to the right. On IE the sbutton no the first line floats all the way to right as expected, but the subsequent lines float just to the left of the sbutton above them:

```
Something some other text ----------------------------------[Delete]
Something Else some other text ---------------------[Delete]--------
```

This is related to paddings and margins on the sbutton:

```
.sbutton {
    background-color: #2E3239; color: white; border: 1px solid gray;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS"; font-size: 90%; padding: 1px 3px; margin: 2px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px;
}
```

If I remove the padding and margin they all float as expected.

Here's the HMTL:

```
<li>
     <span class="left"><b>Something</b> (#1102) some other text</span> 
     <span class="right"><a href="#" class="sbutton">Delete</a></span> 
</li> 
<li>
     <span class="left"><b>Something Else</b> (#1103) some other text</span> 
     <span class="right"><a href="#" class="sbutton">Delete</a></span> 
</li>
```

I get similar behavior on FF and Chrome if I remove the outer span (the one with class "right").

Why is this happening, and what's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clear your floats. Here's one way of doing it:

```
.clear {
    clear:both;
    font-size:0;
}

<li>
     <span class="left"><b>Something</b> (#1102) some other text</span> 
     <span class="right"><a href="#" class="sbutton">Delete</a></span> 
     <span class='clear'></span>
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks Diodeus. Any idea why that's not necessary on FF and Chrome?

Comment: They do. You were just lucky this time :) Also, start with a CSS reset: http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/

Answer (score 0):

@parand - it's not necessary because IE has a different box model than FF or Webkit (which is the engine that powers chrome & safari, among others). By forcing this clear, it's a workaround from the differences.